# SwiftUI View Not Updating with Firestore Data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm developing a SwiftUI app that fetches data from Firestore and displays it in a view contained within a third-party bottom sheet component. Although my AdminPostViewModel successfully fetches data from Firestore (confirmed via print statements showing the correct number of fetched posts), the posts do not appear in my HomeView's bottom sheet.

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import SwiftUI
import Combine


class AdminPostViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [AdminPost]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()


    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("adminsPosts").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents in 'adminsPosts' collection")
                return
            }
            self.posts = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> AdminPost? in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: AdminPost.self)
            }
            print("Fetched \(documents.count) posts.") //successful print 
            self.posts.forEach { post in
                print("Post titlle: \(post.title)") //No successful print 
            }


        }
    }

}
```

```
struct AdminPost: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
    var body: String
    var tags: String
    var imageUrl: String 
    var timestamp: Date
    var isTrending: Bool 
    var views: InT
    var numberOfComments: Int 
    var numberOfReactions: Int
    var isFeatured: Bool 
    
    
}
```

```
//HomeView.swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = AdminPostViewModel()

    var body: some View {
          .bottomSheet(bottomSheetPosition: self.$bottomSheetPosition, switchablePositions: [
                    .relative(0.4),
                    .relativeTop(0.975)
                ], headerContent: {
                    Text("The Latest")
                        .padding(.leading,13)
                        .font(.system(size: 22))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                        
                }) {
                    
                    ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in 
                         NewsContentView(post: post)
                             .padding()
                     }
                    
                    
                }
                
  
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.fetchData()
                }
    }
}
```

```
// NewsContentView.swift
struct NewsContentView: View {
    var post: AdminPost

    var body: some View {
        var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    if post.isTrending {
                        Text("Trending")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                    Text(post.title)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(post.body)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
                Spacer()
                // AsyncImage replacement for iOS 15 and newer
                if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: post.imageUrl)) { phase in
                        if let image = phase.image {
                            image.resizable()
                                 .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        } else if phase.error != nil {
                            Color.gray // Indicates an error.
                        } else {
                            Color.gray // Placeholder while loading.
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                } else {
                    // Fallback for iOS versions before 15
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("10 mins ago") // Placeholder for dynamic timestamp
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup")
                    Text(String(post.numberOfReactions))
                }
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "message")
                    Text(String(post.numberOfComments))
                }
                Button("Share", action: {})
            }
            .padding(.top, 5)
            Divider().padding(.horizontal, -16)
        }
        .padding(.bottom)
    }
}
```

Given that the issue persists even after removing the third-party bottom sheet and using a standard SwiftUI ScrollView, the problem likely lies elsewhere other than the bottom sheet. If I add static data to NewsContentView,the data displays correctly in the ForEachLoop in HomeView so it's definitely an issue with firestore I assume?

The issue is that the NewsContentView in the HomeView is not displaying the data fetched from the Firestore 'adminsPosts' collection. The intended solution is to ensure that the AdminPostViewModel fetches and retains the Firestore data correctly, and that the HomeView observes and displays this data within its view hierarchy, specifically in the bottom sheet where the NewsContentView is supposed to show the posts.

Comment: could you try this: `struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = AdminPostViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in
            Text(post.title)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}`  to see if the basics works.

Comment: Firestore makes its delivery to AdminPostViewModel asynchronously.  But it seems that AdminPostViewModel is making its delivery to HomeView synchronously because you just call fetchData with `onAppear` without `await` or do not use Combine?

Comment: May I ask how many records the adminsPosts collection has?

Comment: @ElTomato adminsPosts has two records. When homeview appears, it successfully prints that it fetched 2 posts. As for your last comment, I will look into incorporating combine tonight!

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks I’ll give it a try and let you know!

Comment: I think you should show the entire sheet`View` with NewsContentView along with @EnvironmentObject data records from HomeView.

Comment: @ElTomato updated the code in the question , let me know if you have enough info! thx

Comment: I am afraid you are showing a lot of irrelevant lines of code + meaninglessly empty lines of code this time.  Why do you need to show `Map`?  `MapCameraPosition`? `@Environment(\.colorScheme)`?  How are they relevant to your Firestore question?

Comment: @ElTomato My apologies I misunderstood your previous request I reckon. Those lines are not revenant, I restored the question to its previous state.

Comment: @ElTomato Since the print statement for the fetched post count works but individual post titles don't print, the issue likely lies in how the documents are being mapped to the model? I'll have to continue troubleshooting...

Comment: The print statement can make delivery at any time that pleases it.  And Firebase has nothing to do with the difficulty you are having.  Meanwhile, I have already created a sample Firestore project.  So far, it has no problem showing two records of title, body, date.  I'll see tomorrow if it can show `AsyncImage` images.

Comment: @ElTomato Do you mind comparing your working sample?  This could help me identify the discrepancies. 

I thought my implementation for fetching, handling, and displaying data in SwiftUI using Firestore followed the general practices and patterns recommended for such this task.

Tomorrow I’ll double check view updates, the data fetching logic, and data model alignment. Getting burnt out, probably starting to slip..

Comment: @ElTomato figured it out. Just needed sleep lol, thank you for assisting me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue.The main change I made was to simplify the AdminPost struct by removing several properties such as tags, timestamp, views, and isFeatured.

This was what I had before

```
struct AdminPost: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
    var body: String
    var tags: String // The tags of the post
    var imageUrl: String // Cover Image URL for the post
    var timestamp: Date
    var isTrending: Bool // Trending label only shows if post is trending
    var views: Int // The number of views this post has
    var numberOfComments: Int // Number of comments on the post
    var numberOfReactions: Int // Numboer of reactions on the post
    var isFeatured: Bool // Will pin post to top of scroll view if true
    
    
}
```

I changed it to this

```
struct AdminPost: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
    var body: String
    var imageUrl: String // Cover Image URL for the post
    var isTrending: Bool // Trending label only shows if post is trending
    var numberOfComments: Int // Number of comments on the post
    var numberOfReactions: Int // Numboer of reactions on the post


}
```

The likely reason this change allowed the data to display in the HomeView is due to a mismatch between my data model in the app and the actual data structure in Firestore. If my data model expects certain fields that are missing in the Firestore documents, or if there's a type mismatch (for example, expecting a Date object where the document might store a timestamp as a String), decoding will fail, resulting in no data being displayed.

By simplifying the AdminPost struct, I ensured that only the existing and correctly typed fields were expected, thus the decoding succeeded, and the data could be displayed. This kind of issue is common when working with Codable in Swift, as the decoding process requires that the data types and structure match exactly between the model and the data source. Should've known.... If they don't, the decoder won't be able to create an instance of my data model, resulting in an empty array or optional values not being filled.

For anyone else having this issue in the future - Always ensure that your model properties reflect the actual data structure and types in Firestore to avoid this. If optional data might be missing, make sure to mark these properties as optional (String?, Int?, Bool?, etc.) in your Swift model to prevent decoding failures.

Thank you for everyone that helped.